# querying SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is time and milemarkers:

```
08:00 101.2
08:45 109.8
09:15 109.8
09:30 111.0
10:00 114.6
```

I need output that looks like this:

```
08:00-08:45 101.1-109.8
08:45-09:15 109.8-109.8
09:15-09:30 109.8-111.0
09:30-10:00 111.0-114.6
```

I figure I need 2 identical recordsets and somehow tie the first record of one to the second record of the other, but am clueless on how to accomplish that (or how to ask the question).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ginny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way to do it is:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20f9d/5/0)

```
select cast(A.TIME_COL as varchar) + ' - ' + cast(B.TIME_COL as varchar), 
    cast(A.MILES as varchar) + ' - ' +  cast(B.MILES as varchar)
from (select row_number() OVER (order by time_col) ID, * from TABLE_A) A 
inner join (select row_number() OVER (order by time_col) ID, * from TABLE_A) B
    on A.ID = B.ID - 1
```

**UPDATE**: this query will only works for SQL Server 2008 and upwards and obviously not answer your question. I will not erase the answer cause it can be helpful for othe people.

**UPDATE2**: It works on [SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Very helpful, and more like I imagined it working, but without a unique record id in the table, I was unsure how to join the two recordsets together.

Answer (score 2):

The following query will get the next values:

```
select tm.*,
       (select top 1 time
        from timemilemarkers tm2
        where tm2.time > tm.time
        order by 1 desc
       ) as nexttime,
       (select top 1 milemarker
        from timemilemarkers tm2
        where tm2.time > tm.time
        order by 1 desc
       ) as nextmilemarker
from timemilemarkers tm;
```

You can put them into the form you want with something like:

```
select concat_ws('-', milemarker, nextmilemarker), concat_ws('-', time, nexttime)
from (select tm.*,
             (select top 1 time
              from timemilemarkers tm2
              where tm2.time > tm.time
              order by 1 desc
             ) as nexttime,
             (select top 1 milemarker
              from timemilemarkers tm2
              where tm2.time > tm.time
              order by 1 desc
             ) as nextmilemarker
      from timemilemarkers tm
     ) tm
where nextmilemarker is not null;
```

Comment: ah, perfect, just the clues I was looking for.  However, I don't understand the purpose, or syntax, of the order by clauses in the sub-selects...it seems to return expected results without it.  Also, TOP 1 appears to be required, like (select TOP 1 milemarker from...)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @t table (times  time(0), milemarkers  decimal(5,2))

insert into @t
select '08:00','101.2' union all
select'08:45','109.8' union all
select'09:15','109.8' union all
select'09:30','111.0' union all
select'10:00','114.6'

;With cte1 as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by times)rn from @t
)
,cte2 as
(select max(rn) rn1 from cte1)
, cte as
(select 
(select times from cte1 where rn=1)lowerlimit,(select times from cte1 where rn=2)upperlimit,
(select milemarkers from cte1 where rn=1)lowerlimit1,(select milemarkers from cte1 where rn=2)upperlimit1
,1 rn  from cte1
union all
select upperlimit,(select times from cte1 where rn=a.rn+2) 
,upperlimit1,(select milemarkers from cte1 where rn=a.rn+2)
,rn+1
 from cte a where a.rn<(select rn1  from cte2)
) 

select distinct cast(lowerlimit as varchar(10))+'-'+cast(upperlimit as varchar(10)) ,
cast(lowerlimit1 as varchar(10))+'-'+cast(upperlimit1 as varchar(10))
from cte a where a.rn<(select rn1  from cte2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE we can get the OutPut it is also other way to do Find below query

```
DECLARE  @TABLE_A  table(time_col time, miles float)

insert into @TABLE_A values ('08:00',101.2)
insert into @TABLE_A values ('08:45',109.8)
insert into @TABLE_A values ('09:15',109.8)
insert into @TABLE_A values ('09:30',111.0)
insert into @TABLE_A values ('10:00',114.6)

;WITH CTE  AS
(
SELECT t.time_col,t.miles,t.RN FROM 
(
Select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY time_col )RN,* FRom @TABLE_A 
)t
INNER JOIN (
Select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY time_col )RN,* FRom @TABLE_A 
)tt 
ON t.RN = tt.RN 
)
,CTE2(TimeSpan,Miles) AS
(
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR,c.time_col,108) +'-'+ 
(Select CONVERT(VARCHAR,time_col,108) FROM CTE WHERE RN = cc.RN + 1) As TimeSpan,
 CAST(c.miles AS VARCHAR) +' - '+ (Select CAST(miles AS VARCHAR) FROM CTE WHERE RN = CC.RN + 1)AS Miles  FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN CTE CC
ON CC.miles = c.miles
AND CC.time_col = c.time_col
)
Select TimeSpan,Miles from CTE2
WHERE TimeSpan IS NOT NULL
```